# How do I convince my co-workers to position me as CEO?

Tags: management, project-management, promotion, startup

Me and a bunch of college graduates are in the beginning process of making a video game development startup. I was curious as to any arguments to use to position a person as CEO.

Our team agrees that I have the most experience technically, and maybe I could use this to my advantage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be better asking this on http://answers.onstartups.com

Comment: Where's the initial equity coming from?

Comment: Why do you think you're more suited to the job than the others? Just wanting to boss people around (which you seem to want to do if you can't answer that question with real arguments) is the worst of all reasons.

Comment: You think technical experience is what makes good CEOs ?

Comment: Just read their FAQ first. OnStartups is a Stack Exchange site just like Workplace SE, so the fact that this question is too broad may make it tough there as well. If you do post a question there, please be sure to provide more detail so it won't get closed. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 7):

> I was curious as to any arguments to use to position a person as CEO.

The *only* valid argument to use is "I am the best person for this job."

You need to decide what you think the role of the CEO should be in your new company. For many startups, funding, sales, and marketing are most important, not technical ability. But your mileage may vary.

Express your vision for the company, how you plan to lead it there, and why you are uniquely qualified to be that leader.

Comment: If you need to argue that you are the best person for CEO, you probably AREN'T the best person for CEO, a CEO should really stand out and have the drive, personality and guts to make the most of it.  If people don't see this now, they REALLY won't when you are CEO.

Comment: @Joe, in that case there would be a CEO in title only, and it shouldn't be a big deal. You could draw straws, or pick it randomly, or if nobody cares (because it's just a bunch of college graduates) then it shouldn't take convincing. From the question, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the most experienced technically, you are probaly the least suited to be CEO as that is a totaly nontechnical position. This job is Sales and finance and schmoozing investors and making plans for the company in terms of hiring, marketing, policy, etc. This is not a job that a person who enjoys programming will likely do well. If you are serious about a successful start-up, hire a business person with an MBA and marketing experience and financial connections for this job.

Comment: This answer relies solely on stereotypes.

Comment: It might help for you to add some sources to your answer (and they are very easy to find): For example: http://www.iseff.com/post/49861932184/the-curse-of-the-technical-ceo